# ReferenceError: SpreadsheetApp is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I get "ReferenceError: SpreadsheetApp is not defined" when i run the above code. Is there any error?
This is working in script editor but not working in separate file

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Site</title>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>

<script>
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1-wYHx2ynT1fMAUKHSeRDBABjE_cAbJ2tfBP_deKjhGs');
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =ss.getName();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Google Apps Script tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles). For the most part, GAS is all server-side scripting, whereas you're trying to gain client-side access to a spreadsheet. It doesn't work like that. You'll need to follow one of the tutorials and open the script editor to begin writing your code.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll go through those tutorials.

Comment: this is working in script editor but not working in separate file

Comment: That's the idea... it doesn't work in a separate file.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you really need client-side scripting, you can look into the HTML Service and google.script.run: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect call function in a way html apps script allows you. Please have a look at simple line below, which permits you to access any function

a file called "lookatme.html"

```
</script>
function doStuff() {
google.script.run.doStuff()
console.log("ggg")
  }
        </script>
```

if it is a .gs extension file unlike html file, it will recognize the code below and any extended apps scripts' built-in functions

a file called "anyfile.gs"

```
function doStuff() {

console.log("ggg")
// google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo)
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i9of_RcoDih65x2h7-agSdCaUSvc1fvfOm4Y7dQEb-s/edit#gid=0")
var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data")
ws.appendRow(["name"])

  }
```