# How to set a range of values from Google Sheets to <datalist>

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, input, html-datalist

I have some Google Sheet that has an editable list of positions ('Items'!A1:A). I also have another table that writes data from a page created in Google Web Apps using the  method. I need this  to contain a  with values from the range of the first sheets.

In one of the topics I found the following script:

```
<script>
  var datalist = document.getElementById('wrkList');
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  var myList = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'];

  // Prepare the option elements to be rendered.
  myList.forEach(function(wrk) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    var text = document.createTextNode(wrk);

    option.value = wrk;
    option.appendChild(text);
    fragment.appendChild(option);
  });

  // Append all of them to DOM.
  datalist.appendChild(fragment);
</script>
```

How to pass values from the range of the first Google Sheeets ('Items'!A1:A) to the myList variable?

**UPD.** I will try to explain in more detail what I need.

The Web Apps page has an input field:

```
<input type="text" list="wrkList" />
  <datalist id="wrkList"></datalist>
```

And function in .gs:

```
function itemsList() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1WeO8SyHj259jashQKXZ0WT_saSZHgk31yAQ1kZqiWpc').getSheetByName("Items");
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myList = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastrow).getValues();
  return myList;
}
```

I need values obtained by itemsList() function to be passed as value to datalist

Comment: Hi ZxNuClear, did you have a look at my example below? Does that not answer your question of how to pass values between `.gs` and the "front-end" ?

Comment: Hi @iansedano. Your example works, but I, due to poor knowledge, do not know how to apply it to my problem. If you write a ready-made version, then it will be great.

Comment: What I need I wrote in my first post after UPD.

Comment: ZxNuClear, I have updated my answer, I don't have your data so I had to guess some parts, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @iansedano This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much! Everything works great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Sample "server client" or "client server" communication with Apps Script

Here is a minimal example, showing how to get your data as an array into the front-end.

#### Code.gs

```js
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index")
}

function getInfo() {
  let file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheet = file.getSheetByName("Items");
  let range = sheet.getRange("A1:A");
  let values = range.getValues();

  return JSON.stringify(values);
}
```

#### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <button id=main>Run</button>

<script>   
function main(){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(handleInfo).getInfo()
}

function handleInfo(info){
  console.log(JSON.parse(info))
}

const mainButton = document.getElementById("main")
mainButton.addEventListener('click', () => main())
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

If you run this, then you should get the range logged to the console.

You may not need the `JSON.stringify` `JSON.parse` - if your data is only numbers and strings. If it is anything like a date, then you will need it.

### Your code so far

What you seem to be doing is trying to call Apps Script specific things from a plain JavaScript context. Things like `SpreadsheetApp` don't exist in JavaScript, only in Apps Script. So the `<script>` tags in your web app cannot contain anything that references the spreadsheet directly. You need to use the construct of

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(handleInfo).itemsList()
```

This will send a request to the Apps Script to run `itemsList()` in a `.gs` file. Whatever that function returns will be used as an argument for the local `handleInfo` function. That is, when the Apps Script function succeeds, it will do this:

```
handleInfo([with whatever itemsList returns])
```

Ideally you make `itemsList` return a simple array of strings, so that you can easily create `<option>` elements to insert into your datalist.

### Working example

I don't know what your data looks like so I invented some for myself:

[image]

I also don't know what the rest of your script looks like or the name of your `html` file, so I have filled in the blanks as much as I can.

I also had to test with my own Spreadsheet ID, though in the example below I have used the one you provided.

#### Code.gs

```js
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index")
}

function itemsList() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1WeO8SyHj259jashQKXZ0WT_saSZHgk31yAQ1kZqiWpc').getSheetByName("Items");
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myList = sheet.getRange(1,1,lastrow).getValues();
  // This line is to transform the array from [[1], [2], [3]] to [1,2,3]
  myList = myList.map(item => item[0])
  return JSON.stringify(myList); // JSON.stringify may not be neccesary
}
```

#### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <input type="text" list="wrkList"/>
  <datalist id="wrkList"></datalist>
</body>

<script>
function handleInfo(info){
  const list = JSON.parse(info) // JSON.parse needed if you used JSON.stringify in Code.gs
  
  // select datalist element
  const datalist = document.getElementById('wrkList')

  // forEach loop to create and append an option element for each item in list
  list.forEach(item => {
    const option = document.createElement('option')
    option.setAttribute('value', item)
    datalist.appendChild(option)
  })
}

// execute the itemsList function in code.gs and with the response
// execute the handleInfo function.
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(handleInfo).itemsList()
</script>

</html>
```

Once delplyed, this loads an HTML page with this:

[image]

#### References

- [JSON Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)
- [Client-Server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code:

```
<script>
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1WeO8SyHj259jashQKXZ0WT_saSZHgk31yAQ1kZqiWpc').getSheetByName("Items");
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  
  var datalist = document.getElementById('wrkList');
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  var myList = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastrow).getValues();

  // Prepare the option elements to be rendered.
  myList.forEach(function(wrk) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    var text = document.createTextNode(wrk);

    option.value = wrk;
    option.appendChild(text);
    fragment.appendChild(option);
  });

  // Append all of them to DOM.
  datalist.appendChild(fragment);
</script>
```

But got this error in the Console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: SpreadsheetApp is not defined
> at userCodeAppPanel:2

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `SpreadsheetApp.openById()`.

You can find the documentation for SpreadsheetApp [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid).

Please see the adapted code below:

```js
  var datalist = document.getElementById('wrkList');
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  var myList = SpreadsheetApp.openById('THE_ID_OF_YOUR_SPREADSHEET').getSheetByName('THE_SHEET_NAME').getRange('THE_RANGE').getValue();

  // Prepare the option elements to be rendered.
  myList.forEach(function(wrk) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    var text = document.createTextNode(wrk);

    option.value = wrk;
    option.appendChild(text);
    fragment.appendChild(option);
  });

  // Append all of them to DOM.
  datalist.appendChild(fragment);
```

Comment: @ZxNuClear I don't have 50 reputation so I can't comment on your second post, but let me try to answer it here: SpreadsheetApp is run on Google's servers where they are defined, so the class won't work, unless you run it Script Editor see here: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27295840/referenceerror-spreadsheetapp-is-not-defined). Try running the code from the spreadsheet you are trying to write to.

Comment: Unfortunately, my knowledge is not enough to write the code correctly

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve with the code above. Maybe you try to explain it in a bit more detail?

Comment: I updated my first post. I tried to explain what exactly I need.